# Sorted sub-sequence of given size k

Tags: algorithm

Looking to find longest increasing sub-sequence of given size, but the following solution(found over stack overflow) works only in some cases but doesn't satisfy all the corner cases.

```
function increasingSubSeq(array, k) {
    if(array.length < k) 
        return;
    var maxCount = 0, count = 0;
    var prev = array[0];
    var m = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
        if(prev <= array[i]) {
            count++; 
            m.push(array[i]);   
            if(m.length === k){
                break;
            }

        } else {
            count = 1;
        }
        if(count > maxCount) 
            maxCount = count;

        prev = array[i];
    }
    return m;
}
```

Correct o/p return

increasingSubSeq([3,1,4,2,5,1,6,4,7], 4); should return only [3,4,5,6] 
increasingSubSeq([3,1,4,2,5,1,6,4,7], 2); should return only [3,4]

But the following i/p returns wrong answer

increasingSubSeq([1,5,2,3,4],4) it returns [1,5,3,4] instead of [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 0):

The above algorithm is wrong the reason why 3 gets inserted in the list is because you assign prev = array[i], now at i=2, prev = 2 and count becomes 1, now when i = 3, in this case you check 3 >= 2 and now in this case count becomes 3 but you see the catch here, your m array gets inserted with 3 and your m.length = 3 which causes the condition to hit m.length == k and that is why your condition is met.

Here is your updated code but again, it doesn't guarantee all the corner cases

```
function increasingSubSeq(array, k) {
if(array.length < k) 
    return;
var maxCount = 0, count = 0;
var prev = array[0];
var m = [];
var flag = 0;
for(var i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
    if(prev <= array[i]) {
        count++; 
        m.push(array[i]);   
        if(maxCount === k){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }

    } else {
        count = 1;
    }
    if(count > maxCount) 
        maxCount = count;

    prev = array[i];
}
if (flag == 0) {
  return -1;
}
return m;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not working even for the i/p  i provided above, 

increasingSubSeq([3,1,4,2,5,1,6,4,7], 4);     returns   -1
increasingSubSeq([1,5,2,3,4], 4);  returns -1